# Is it possible to use a static resource from another dictionary inside a data template?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `DataTemplate` I'm trying to define and inside of that I have a `Button` I would like to set the style of. Currently I have a `UserControl` with `MergedDictionaries`... probably better to show some code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- MyButtonStyle is in this dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms appx:///Dictionaries/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Here is the button I want to apply the style to -->
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I want to set the style of `Button` inside the `DataTemplate` to `MyButtonStyle` which is located in my `ButtonStyles.xaml`. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Resource `MyButtonStyle` is not found
```

How do I correctly reference the resource in my example?

Comment: Could you move your Dictionary to Application's Resources?

Comment: We can't really do that at this point.

Comment: That stinks. So I guess the only solution for us is to copy the style directly into the local resource dictionary.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. The code should work since it is in Dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

StaticResource will search resources in following order:

1. All resources that are declared earlier in the same dictionary
2. Resources in the MergedDictionaries
3. Application resources

It will not search in the sibling merged dictionaries.

In your case, `MyButtonStyle` is not included in the ResourceDictionary with `MyDataTemplate`, nor in any of its MergedDictionaries. What you need is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MyButtonStyle is in this dictionary -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms appx:///Dictionaries/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
             <Grid>
                <!-- Here is the button I want to apply the style to -->
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    <ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `The attachable property MergedDictionaries was not found in type ResourceDictionary`

Comment: isn't your solution missing `<ResourceDictionary></ResourceDictionary>` after `<UserControl.Resources>`?

Comment: This still doesn't solve my issue :/ Are you able to bind the style? Did you create a solution to test this?

Comment: @visc Sorry, I don't have Visual Studio here to test it. I can't think of what else can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@nevermind's commend about the order was very precise. However, in order to import a `ResourceDictionary` is used the following path

```xml
<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAssemblyName;component/Folder1/Folder2/Res.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
```